# Is this a displacement or just a blockage?

Tags: plumbing, sewer, blockage

We just had an inspection done on a house we are buying, and during the sewer scope, the inspector found what he believes to be a displacement. In the [video](https://youtu.be/WpA26NQwUL8?t=20), at about 0:44, there is something suspicious on the top, and behind that, there is a substantial amount of water that wouldn't be explained by rain or any other discharge. However, the sellers have since said this:

> The plumber came on Saturday and said there is nothing wrong with the pipes based on the video. He just recommended hydro jetting the pipes which will make them basically like new.

The sellers are going to have hydrojetting done, and we're asking for video proof. In the meantime, I was wondering if any of you have an opinion on whether it's reasonable that hydrojetting can fix it?

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the pipes are displaced all jetting will do is clean out the debris that have made there way into the pipe, so yes you want confirmation. If the pipes are separated soil will continue to find its way into the drain, possibly causing a large enough void that can create a failure in a slab above and possible backups. I believe the problem was at ~ 1 minute , till about 1:18, I also saw something but it could just be a clump of something that got stuck, jetting and verification to make sure should not be a big deal. 
I would ask for a second video just to be sure , the rest of the pipe is old but looks in good shape.

Comment: You definitely want a second video. That area noted by Ed looks suspicious.

Comment: Thank you, Ed! I appreciate your time. When I get the post-hydrojetting video, I will post it for posterity.

Comment: [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j1GIhkrst6A) is the video after the hydrojetting. They really speed through it, almost as if they don't want us to really see.